# select some lines as a group then give each line same label in same group in txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract some lines of txt file between two patterns as different groups and give each line a same number as a label in each group.(last column input the group label ) for example, have data:

```
==g1
a 1 2 3 4
b 2 1 2 3
~~
==g2
c 2...
d 1...
...
```

I want to get output like

```
a 1 2 3 4 1
b 2 1 2 3 1
c 2 ...   2
d 1 ...   2
...
```

I use python 3.7

```
with open('input.txt') as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    copy = False
    for line in infile:
        #ng as the new label in each group
        ng=0
        if line.strip() == "start":
            copy = True
            continue
        elif line.startswith ('with'):
            copy = False
            continue
        elif copy:
            ng=ng+1
            line=line.rstrip('\n') +'\t'+ str(ng)+'\n'
            outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution like [this](https://repl.it/repls/PutridSilverExabyte) ?

Comment: hi,Codeit. actually, my raw data each group includes different length of data,so I can not set step at 4 in range(0,len(lines),4) here. so what can i do ?

Comment: hi,ForceBru. yes, my code has problem it doesnt  work perfectly to get what I want. but I do not know how to change it. thks